# How do I override the review tab on OnePage Checkout

Tags: magento

I am writing a custom module to change the display of the table on checkout/onepage/onepage.phtml I can see in checkout.xml how it gets declared with

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="checkout.onepage.review" as="review" template="checkout/onepage/review.phtml">
     <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
</block>
```

What I can not figure out is how to set up the /app/design/frontend/{location}/{theme}/layout/{module}.xml file to override the current review.phtml template with the new one. My thought would be to remove the current one and reload with the new one but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing i can see is the directory you are using is incorrect.

it should be

```
app/design/frontend/{location}/{theme}/layout/{module}.xml
```

instead of

```
app/layout/frontend/{location}/{theme}/layout/{module}.xml
```

Also, i'm not sure exactly what you want to do with regards to overriding the review layout table, but the following will replace the review template with your own:

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="root">
       <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/onepage/your_template.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

Secondly, if you are creating a custom module and want your layout file to be loaded, you have to declare the layout update in your modules config.xml.  have you done this?

It would look something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Company_Your_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Your_Company_Your_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <yourmodule>
                    <file>yourmodule.xml</file>
                </yourmodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Finaly, depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may not require a module just to override the checkout review table.

If the sole purpose of the module is simple to override the checkout layout, then it would probably be sufficient to just override the layout by using one of the following methods:

1. Use local.xml

   Create a local.xml file in your themes layout directory:

   /app/design/frontend/{location}/{theme}/layout/{module}.xml

   and use this for all core layout overrides.  There are lots of benefits to this.
2. Copy the base checkout.xml layout file to your theme

   Copy app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml
   To app/design/frontend/{location}/{theme}/layout/checkout.xml

Comment: FYI, I fixed the question because of the directory issue you mentioned. When I use the setTemplate call, the page still continues to load the original table. My thinking is that this is happening because the .phtml still needs to be in checkout/onepage/review for the system to see it. However, I want it to live in the module because I need to call specific classes which will change the display output. The module is doing a lot more than changing the table but that part is what I am getting hung on. It is loading the module's XML, just not switching the template.

Comment: @GregDemetrick - Just to say, the path you have is still wrong, im assuming its just a typo :) Have you cleared the cache?  Also, can you post your config.xml and layout.xml files?

Comment: I think my solution is at http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/how_to_customize_frontend_template_f.e._review.phtml_of_onepage_checkout I am changing the template name without changing the block type. Giving that a try now.